# In a sine wave, what is the minimum possible distance between two particles which always have the same speed?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, speed

I was going through my book when I came across this statement which was stated as a fact.

'That the minimum distance between two particles **always** having the same speed is $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength. '
But why is it so?

---

I understand that my book refers to any pair of points like A and B ( figure attached ) but why can't there exist a pair of points like C and D which might also have their speeds equal? In that case, the distance is even lesser than half the wavelength.
How can we get a mathematical explanation of this?

[image: FIGURE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is poorly worded, but it must mean *always* having the same speed, rather than just momentarily.

Two particles that are separated by a distance of $k\lambda$ will have a phase difference of $2 \pi k$. But if the particles *always* have the same speed then their phase difference must be a multiple of $\pi$.

(Why ? Suppose the phase difference is, say, $\frac \pi 2$. Then when one particle is at maximum amplitude and so stationary, the other particle will be at minimum amplitude and have maximum speed.)

But if $2 \pi k = n \pi$ then $k = \frac n 2 $. And the smallest non-zero value of $k$ is therefore $\pm \frac 1 2$, when the distance between the particles is $ \frac \lambda 2$.

Comment: Yes you're right. Maybe I should have paid more attention to the 'always'. I have added that in my post. Anyways, It's clear now. Thank you!